# Blazor save basic filter data to browser when reloading page

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, .net-5

How can I save data from a object to the browser and retrieve that data using server-side Blazor?

I have a model to filter an overview, but if you navigate away from the overview and come back the filter is gone. It's a pretty advanced filter so filling it out every time is not really an option.

Let's do this simplified example:

```cs
public class OverviewFilterModel
{
  public string Keywords { get; set; }

  public int PartnerId { get; set; }

  public EnumStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

```
public enum EnumStatus
{
  A,
  B,
  C
}
```

How do I save above model in browser and retrieve it again? Or is there no such thing? I do not want to use an SQL database for this, or anything server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Blazored.LocalStorage. Its a third party library developed by Chris Sainty to store data in your browser which persists across pages and you can access that data from a new tab as well.
Just pull the library from Nuget, register the service in your Startup class, inject it into any page or component you want and then store whatever data you want in the browser local storage.

```
@inject Blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService localStorage
```

@code {

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await localStorage.SetItemAsync("name", "John Smith");
    var name = await localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("name");
}
```

}

You can add complex nested objects as well.
You can verify the data/model that you have stored in your browser local storage if you open developer options.

Here's the github repo link. You will find all the documentation here :
https://github.com/Blazored/LocalStorage

Comment: Thanks! Weird that this is not in stock Blazor

Comment: I asked for local storage, but for my use case the other library from Blazored makes more sense: https://github.com/Blazored/SessionStorage thanks for sharing this